# Python : Dataframe transformation tuples as columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to transform a dataframe similar to the one below:

```
 index apple
 1      [(red,3),(green,2)]
 1      [(red,3)]
 1      [(yellow,9),(red,3)]
 1      [(green,2),(yellow,9)]
 1      [(green,2),(yellow,9), (pink,50)]
 2      [(yellow,14),(red,1)]
 2      [(green,5)]
```

into this:

```
 index  apple_red apple_green apple_yellow apple_pink
 1       3         2           9            50
 2       1         5           14           0
```

Note that tuples are unique per index in the original table
Any idea how do to this ?

Thanks

Comment: SO is no code-writing service. Please post what you've tried so far. What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

- use `DataFrame` constructor with `list comprehension`
- reshape by  [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and remove duplicates by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by columns created from tuples
- last rehape by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html)
- last [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html), [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

---

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([dict(x) for x in df['apple']], index=df.index) \
        .stack() \
        .astype(int) \
        .reset_index(name='val') \
        .drop_duplicates(['level_1','val']) \
        .set_index(['index', 'level_1'])['val'] \
        .unstack(fill_value=0) \
        .add_prefix('apple_') \
        .rename_axis(None) \
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1) \
        .reset_index()
print (df1)
   index  apple_green  apple_pink  apple_red  apple_yellow
0      1            2          50          3             9
1      2            5           0          1            14
```

Comment: Glad can help, it was interesting problem!